# Does the derivative of the Fourier series $\sum_{k\geq2}\frac{1}{k^2\log k}\cos kt$ exist?

Tags: sequences-and-series, derivatives, fourier-series

Does the derivative of the Fourier series $\sum_{k\geq2}\frac{1}{k^2\log k}\cos kt$ exist?

I wanted to use the following sufficient condition for this problem

> **Theorem.** Let $a_k(t)$ be differentiable. If a series of functions $\sum_{k}a_k(t)$ is such that $\sum_ka_k'(t)$ converges uniformly in $[a,b]$, and $\sum_{k}a_k(t)$ converges at ont point in $(a,b)$, then $\sum_ka(t)$ converges in $[a,b]$ and its derivative is $\sum_ka_k'(t)$.

But this theorem does not seem to be applicable to the series above, because I can't prove that $-\sum_k\frac{1}{k\log k}\sin kt$ is uniformly convergent. However, a book that I am reading says that it does have a derivative. How can I prove it?

Comment: Having a derivative (in a classical sense) is a weaker requirement, and that derivative being obtained as the termwise derivative of the Fourier series...

Comment: @paulgarrett Can you provide a proof or a theorem that guarantees this assertion?

Comment: My words were a little garbled in my previous comment: having a derivative (at least almost everywhere) is a weaker condition than that the derivative is obtained by differentiating the Fourier series termwise (unless we allow distributional derivatives and such...). Your example is an explicit instance. Baire category in fact proves that this is "typical". This kind of mildly negative assertion would be one of the basic applications of Baire category in any source.

Comment: ... so you should not expect to prove that the function is differentiable by differentiating its Fourier series.

Comment: @paulgarrett I did understand what you mean. Let's say I give up trying to differentiate it by differentiating the Fourier series. Then what other method should I use?

Comment: I don't have good advice on this, since this kind of example I interpret exactly as a good reason to look at Sobolev spaces instead of classical spaces of differentiable, etc., functions.